# Proving convergence or divergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have to show the following diverges:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{1/3} -x^{4/3}} dx$$

I am meant to do this without evaluating the integral. I know that I have to split it into:

$$\int_0^{0.5} \frac{1}{x^{1/3} -x^{4/3}} dx + \int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1}{x^{1/3} -x^{4/3}} dx$$

I know that the one on the left converges and the one on the right diverges. How do I prove these two facts? I'm not sure but it may have to do with using direct comparison.

Comment: With the diverges one, thinking about it it should diverge to $+\infty$ if at all (1 over a small positive number is a large positive number) so you'd be looking to show it's more than something you know to diverge. The convergent one doesn't matter then, because something + something tending off to +oo is +oo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{x^{1/3}-x^{4/3}}=\frac{1}{x^{1/3}(1 -x)}.
$$
If $0\le x\le1/2$ then
$$
\frac{1}{x^{1/3}(1-x)}\le\frac{2}{x^{1/3}}.
$$
If $1/2\le x\le1$ then
$$
\frac{1}{x^{1/3}(1-x)}\ge\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$